# Sequelize - how to get all Employees for all Locations

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'll preface this by saying I think my model associations may be incorrect

Basically what i'm trying to do is is return an array of all Employees for a company.

- Get all locations that have the same companyId
- With those locations, get all Profiles tied to the locationId.

Profiles are linked to Locations through Employees.

Below is my code.

The query:

```
 Location.findAll({
        where: { companyId: user.profile.companyId },
        include: [
            {
                model: Employee
            }
        ]
    })
```

This generates the error `"employee is not associated to location!"`.

My models:

```
Employee.belongsTo(Profile)
Employee.belongsTo(Location)

Profile.belongsTo(Company)
Location.belongsTo(Company)

Profile.belongsToMany(Location, {
    through: Employee,
    foreignKey: "profileId"
})

Location.belongsToMany(Profile, {
    through: Employee,
    foreignKey: "locationId"
})
```

EDIT:

Adding Location.hasMany(Employee) allows me to do the query however it still requires a for loop within another for loop to get the correct data structure needed.

```
const locations = await models.Location.findAll({
        where: { companyId: user.profile.companyId },
        include: [{ model: models.Profile }]
    })

    const response = []

    locations.forEach(location => {
        location.profiles.forEach(profile => {
            response.push({ location, profile })
        })
    })

    return response
```

The query below returns what exactly as is however its only for a single location. I need to run the same query but for multiple locations.

```
Employee.findAll({ where: { locationId }, include: [Profile, Location] })
```

Comment: Try to add the relation between Location to Employee with 'hasMany' directive:
    Location.hasMany(Employee)

Comment: @FedericoB. I was able to get it to work after adding the additional relationship that you mentioned. Can you check my EDIT in the original question and let me know if there is a way around that using only sequelize?

Comment: Try to add 'raw: true' after the 'where object' ( { where: {...}, raw: true} ) and check if the new structure returned is better for you.

Comment: Also you can set the 'raw' property and remove the where condition from your last example. if I'm not wrong, you can retrive the list of Employee with the Location associated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified that Location belongsToMany Locations, but you've failed to specify the other way around. You should specify that a Location hasMany Employees.

Specifying `Employee.belongsTo(Location)` allows you to include related Locations with Employees. Specifying `Location.hasMany(Employee)` allows you to include related Employees with Locations.

I was able to recreate your problem and fix it with this line.

```
Location.hasMany(Employee, {
    //...
})
```

Comment: can you check my edit at the bottom of the question? Is there a better way to query for multiple employees at multiple locations?

Comment: If you're looking for Employees, you should run Employee.findAll. Use where to filter in the ones you want. where: { locationId: [ ... ] }.

Comment: i'm looking for Employees based on unknown location ID's. Basically for each location get all of their locations.

Comment: I was able to get it to work though. I'm using sequelize in-conjunction with graphql and I think my graphql schema was incorrect.